# How do we algebraically solve this simple PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have just begun studying PDE's.
My textbook starts with a very simple PDE. I intuitively understand the solution, but it seems like the textbook is doing some "hand-waving" here, and doesn't formally derive the solution:

> [image]

**My question is:** How do we formally derive the equation $$u(x,y)=f(bx-ay)$$
from the PDE we started with, using the **algebraic properties** of PDE's, rather than appeals to geometric intuitions?

**ps. I hope that there is a way to solve this that doesn't involve any preliminary guesswork, which is what some methods use.**

Answer (score 1):

The general method behind this is to look for a curve $(x(t),y(t))$ so that $u(x(t),y(t))$ is a constant along the curve. Such a curve is called a characteristic curve for the equation.

Assume $$u(x,y)=u(x(t),y(t))=f(t)$$
The chain rule gives that
$$f'(t)=u_xx'(t)+u_y y'(t)=0$$
since we want $f$ to be a constant. Comparing this to $au_x+bu_y=0$ we see that
$$x'(t)=a\text{ and }y'(t)=b$$
hence
$$x(t)=at+x_0\text{ and }y(t)=bt+y_0$$
The second equation gives
$$t=\dfrac{y(t)-y_0}{b}$$
hence
$$x(t)=\dfrac{a}{b}y(t)+constant$$
which shows that $u(x,y)$ is constant over the lines $bx-ay=constant$. It is then clear that $u(x,y)$ must be a function of $bx-ay$ for this to hold.

Comment: Could you explain the last step algebraically? why does the fact that $bx−ay=constant$ over that line, imply that $u(x,y)$ is a function of bx−ay? How does this follow algebraically?

Comment: Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. There is a unique line $bx-ay=C$ that goes through $(x,y)$. Then $u(x,y)$ depends only on $C$ according to my calculations, we can write it $f(C)$. This means that $u(x,y)=f(C)=f(bx-ay)$.